# World Problem on writing an equation

Tags: linear-algebra

Question: A community centre offers pottery classes. A \$40 enrolment fee covers supplies and materials, including one bag of clay. Extra bags of clay cost \$15 each. Write an equation to represent the cost of  the class and x bags of clay?

What I got (Which is wrong): 40+15x

Comment: If I enroll I get one bag of clay for free.  so, I pay \$40.  If I enroll and I get one additional bag of clay (two bags total) I pay \$40 and an additional \$15.  If I enroll and I get $x$ total bags of clay, one of which was free, I need to spend \$15 for the remaining $x-1$ bags for a total cost of \$ $40+15(x-1)$

Answer (score 3):

Remember that if only 1 bag of clay is used, the cost is still 40. The enrollment fee covers one bag of clay, thus, it would be 40+15(x-1) or simplified: 25+15x.

Comment: thanks, this helped a lot.